# How can I use the circular Progress bar between two activities properly?

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I have a trouble with the circular progressBar, I have it in background in a layout as invisible. When I want to start the new activity I show it setting visible the layout, it is shown good but the animation of the progressBar works bad it sometimes rotate a little then stop after rotate a little more... It isn't fluently. I try to solve with this but seems that didnt work:

```
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

          progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
          progressLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          final CustomOverlayItem i = item;

          Runnable intentRunnable = new Runnable()
          {
              public void run()
              {
                  Intent intent = new Intent(context,Next.class);
                  startActivityForResult(intent, RETURN_FROM_MONUMENTO);
              }
          };

          intentRunnable.run();
    }

});
```

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: are you doing any network related stuff in the next activity you launch?

Comment: yes, I download images and text from the server.

Comment: Is this code in the AsynTask? if not then this is only causing progressbar to stuck

Comment: not it is not, ok I will try it, thanks.

Comment: if you the ans works for you then accept the answers. that will increase your acceptance score

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part where you receive the data back from the other activity would be interesting. Sending the intent in a Runnable shouldn't be necessary since that is a pretty inexpensive operation (I think). But receiving the result back can result in some heavy operations.
Stuttering animations are normally a sign that you are doing something on the UIThread you shouldn't be doing (or that the device simply is too slow to handle the load of all threads).

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing the network related stuff in the next activity you launch. use `AsyncTask` in that so that will not block the UI thread and it will make the `ProgressBar` Animation Smooth.

Comment: Never do anything network related in the UIThread. Starting from Android 4 (or even 3) an exception will be thrown if you open a socket in the UIThread

Comment: put the Network related stuff in doInBackground method of AsyncTask

Comment: I use if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
         StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
         StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
       } to avoid the exception.

Comment: This is kind of patch. but we should follow standard implementation